# ios: Checking regular expression with NSPredicate - Unable to parse the format string

Tags: ios, regex, nspredicate

I'm trying to validate a username in iOS using a regular expression. To do this I'm using NSPredicate but it's throwing a runtime error.

Here's what I have in my ViewController:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *userNamePattern;
```

And:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    _userNamePattern = @"[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20}";
```

Then in an action when clicking on a button:

```
  NSPredicate *userNameTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:self.userNamePattern];
```

At that bottom line it's throwing this error:

```
   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20}"'
```

Why doesn't it like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just passing the regex pattern into the predicate. You need to give it an actual predicate format string.

Try this for your predicate:

```
NSPredicate *userNameTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", self.userNamePattern];
```